# Proving a lower bound of S bounded below

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $S$ be a set that is bounded below. Prove that a lower bound $w$ of $S$ is the infimum of $S$ if and only if for any $ϵ > 0$ there exists $t$ belonging to $S$ such that $t < w + ϵ$.

I started by saying $\inf S=w \le t$. Let $t$ be $ϵ$ close to $w$ so $t+ϵ=w$ which implies that $t<w+ϵ$.

I am not sure if what I've done is correct and I am even more confused on how to prove the other way ($\le$)

Answer (score 1):

The infimum is defined to be the *largest* lower bound of a set. If a lower bound $w$ of $S$ is not the infimum of $S$, then there is a larger lower bound. Can you then find a suitable $\epsilon$? And conversely, when an $\epsilon$ with the given properties is given, can you find a lower bound of $S$ that is larger than $w$?

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$: Follows directly from the definition of infimum.

$\Leftarrow$: Assume that the condition holds. We want to show that $w=\inf S$. By assumption $w$ is a a lower bound for the set $S$. Suppose $w^*$ is another lowerbound for the set $S$ and suppose that $w<w^*$. Corresponding to $\epsilon =w^*-w>0$, there exists $t\in S$ such that $t<w+\epsilon$, i.e. $t<w^*$. This implies that $w^*$ cannot be a lowerbound for the set $S$, a contradiction. Thus, $w\ge w^*$. This proves that $w=\inf S$.